# what does "openssl FIPS mode(0) unavailable" mean?

Tags: ipsec, openssl, strongswan

I compiled and installed strongswan ipsec vpn successfully, as demonstrated by the fact that the service starts successfully:

> ```
> as3:~# ipsec restart
> Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
> Starting strongSwan 5.0.4 IPsec [starter]...
> as3:~#
> ```

When I run command `ipsec pki --gen --outform pem > caKey.pem` I  see the error:

> ```
> as3:~# ipsec pki --gen --outform pem > caKey.pem
> openssl FIPS mode(0) unavailable
> as3:~#
> ```

What does "openssl FIPS mode(0) unavailable" mean? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This message is logged in strongSwan 5.0.4 if OpenSSL is not compiled with [FIPS mode](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html) enabled, that is if `OPENSSL_FIPS` is not defined in `openssl/opensslconf.h`.

In future releases it will only be logged if the user actually wants to use OpenSSL in FIPS mode, either by setting

```
--with-fips-mode=MODE
    where MODE is either 0 (disabled, default), 1 (enabled), or 2 (Suite B enabled)
```

during [./configure](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Autoconf) or by setting

```
libstrongswan.plugins.openssl.fips_mode
    same values as above, the default is also 0.
```

in [strongswan.conf](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/StrongswanConf) to a value `!= 0`.

Therefore, if you dont't want to use OpenSSL in FIPS mode, as is indicated by the `(0)` in the log message you posted, you can safely ignore this message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed openssl fips mode plugin when you compiled strongswan.

> **libstrongswan.plugins.openssl.fips_mode**
>
> Set OpenSSL FIPS mode: disabled (0), enabled (1), Suite B enabled (2).
>   Defaults to the value configured with the --with-fips-mode option

You can re-compile strongswan, or make change to openssl config:

```
# Default section
XXXX_conf = XXXX_options
...
[ XXXX_options ]
alg_section = algs
...
[ algs ]
fips_mode = yes
...
```

Comment: hi,mr gnouc:i re-compiled strongswan with "--with-fips-mode" parameter but useless,when i run "ipsec pki --gen --outform pem > caKey.pem",i still met the error-"openssl FIPS mode(0) unavailable".

Comment: What is your ssl config? Please post here?